# I am trying to write a program which will display the time and date when the button is clicked upon

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to write a program which - when clicked - will start a new `Thread` and then display date and time, but its not working as I expected. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;


/**
 * @author Hobbit
 *
 */
public class Myapp extends Applet implements Runnable,ActionListener {

    Button b; // I'm creating a button named b
    Thread t;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.applet.Applet#init()
     */     
    public void init() {
        b = new Button(":)");
        add(b);
        b.addActionListener(this);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.awt.Container#paint(java.awt.Graphics)
     */
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Date d = new Date();
        g.drawString(d + "", 50, 50);
        setBackground(Color.green);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
     */
    public void run() {

        while(true) {

            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(600);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.awt.event.ActionListener#actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f) {

        // If the button is clicked then it should trigger the thread
        if (f.getSource() == b);

        { 
            Thread t = new Thread();
            t.start();              
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: your Thread object is an empty one. Maybe what you want is new Thread(this) (because "this" is a runnable)

Comment: If it's not working, what is it doing?

Comment: There's an empty if statement in there as well.

Comment: i have created a new thread inside the if statement .

Comment: If it's working, please answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with the code, but the most important is, that your `Thread` does nothing. If you want it to do something, you need to pass a `Runnable` into it, like below:

```
Runnable myAwesomeRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(new Date());
    }
};

Thread t = new Thread(myAwesomeRunnable);
t.start();
```

I would actally suggest this approach, instead implementing all the interfaces in the `MyApp` class, as I belive it's cleaner and easier to understand what's going on, however, in your example, you could also use:

```
Thread t = new Thread(this);
t.start();
```

since `this` is an instance of `Runnable`.

Another thing is, that you're not really checking which button is pressed. This piece of code:

```
    // If the button is clicked then it should trigger the thread
    if (f.getSource() == b);

    { 
        Thread t = new Thread();
        t.start();              
    }
```

causes thread to start **always**, because of the semicolon after the `if` statement. If you want the `if` to decide whether to start the thread or not, your code should look like this:

```
// If the button is clicked then it should trigger the thread
if (f.getSource() == b) {
    Thread t = new Thread(myAweSomeRunnable);
    t.start();              
}
```